# How to Deserialize float datatype from JSON object in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to pass the below JSON object to an.NET Core 3.1 API endpoint that accepts an object of type Order.

```
{ 
"OrderType" : "Sale",
    "Total" : "100"
}

public class Order (){
public string OrderType {get; set;}
public float Total {get;set;}
}
```

This is giving me the below error. How can I fix this.

Error : "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Single. Path: $.Total | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 21."

Comment: You can use [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/) in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net core 3.1 does not use Newtonsoft.JSON for serialization, it uses its own serializer System.Text.Json.

If you want to use Newtonsoft.JSON in ASP.NET core 3.1,

- download Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson from NuGet package.
- In Startup.cs replace `services.AddControllers();` with `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

You can refer to the below blog for more details on System.Text.Json

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/